# Menu Caret is showing in first child

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a really small problem I want to fix, but I don't know how. So I have a menu in which I added an icon with the "Elegant Icons" font. I want it to show only on elements `li` which have childen `li`s, but it appears on first children on first `li` element. Here is what I mean [Link](http://prntscr.com/d9hud8).

Here is my CSS:

```css
.menu-new li:first-child{
border-left:1px solid black;
}
.menu-new li > a:after{
content: "\37";
font-family: "ElegantIcons";
}
.menu-new li > a:only-child:after{
content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `>` to denote immediate child of `.menu-new`

```css
.menu-new > li:first-child{
border-left:1px solid black;
}
.menu-new > li > a:after{
content: "\37";
font-family: "ElegantIcons";
}
.menu-new > li > a:only-child:after{
content:"";
}
```

Comment: Edit:
I fixed it by adding 
.menu-new li a:only-child:after, .menu-new li li a:after{
content:"";
}
.menu-new li li a:after and it worked